# Replacing dll file in R package

Tags: r, fortran

I am working with the R package glmnet and I want to change something in this package. In this package there is a fortran code compiled to a .dll file. I want to change something in this fortran code, compile it and replace the old dll file by the new one.

For the beginning i just took the original fortran 77 code, transformed it to fortran 95, compiled it to a dll file and replaced it. I expected it should run the same way like before, but it didn't. 
I used the same command glmnet but I got the following error:

> Error in .Fortran("get_int_parms", fdev=double(1), eps=double(1),:
>   "get_int_parms" not available for .Fortran() for package "glmnet"

With R I use the following code:

```
data("Hitters")
dim(Hitters)
Hitters=na.omit(Hitters)

set.seed(1)
train=sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),nrow(Hitters),rep=TRUE)
test=(!train)

x=model.matrix(Salary~.,Hitters)[,-1]
y=Hitters$Salary
grid=10^seq(10,-2,length=100)

lasso.mod=glmnet(x[train,],y[train],alpha=1,lambda=grid)
plot(lasso.mod)
```

Apologies for my english I hope you understand what my problem is.